# Extract a particular column data from rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I am going to ask a very silly question here. I googled it enough but did not get the desired answer.

I want to pick the userid from users table where username="Ryan"

My table name is users and corresponding model name is User. And there is only single row where username="Ryan"

I am using the following code:

```
desired_row=User.where(username: "Ryan")
puts desired_row.userid
```

But the development.log shows me that undefined method userid

I am using postgre as my database.

please tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have a column named "userid" in your table? Maybe it should be "id"?

Comment: yes,,I have the same named column,,, it is something else causing this problem.

Comment: Can you post what ```User.where(username: "Ryan")``` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
desired_row=User.where(username: "Ryan").first
puts desired_row.id
```

Comment: did you add the .first at the end of the query?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.